# I am writing a Java program that is meant to play a version of 20 questions with the user based on their input

Tags: java, if-statement

To do this I am using a lot of nested if/else statements.

I have three main branches (living animal, living plant, non-living thing) and each of these have multiple branches. Making it something like 60 different decisions.

I am having a lot of trouble getting it to cooperate, and control all the if/else statements. I don't have much code for it yet because of having to restart so much but currently I am at:

```
System.out.println("Think of Something");
System.out.println("Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? ");
String user = get.nextLine();

if (user.equals("living animal")); { 
    //starts animal tree
    System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?");
    String user2 = get.nextLine();

    if (user2.equals("feathers")); {
        System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?");
    }
} else if (user2.equals("fur")); {
    System.out.println("is it domesticated?");
    // end animal tree
} else if (user.equals("living plant")); { 
    // start plant tree
    System.out.println("is it a tree?");
    }
} // end method
} //end program
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing out your `if` statements with this syntax:

```
if (user2.equals("feathers"));
{
    System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?");
}
```

However, the body of the `if` block will always execute because you have a semicolon that finishes the statement prematurely:

```
if (user2.equals("feathers")); // <-- The semicolon here finishes the if statement, which means the if statement does nothing
{
    System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?"); // <-- This line is ran no matter what the if statement was
}
```

Basically all you have to do to get the `if` or `else if` statements to work correctly is to remove the unwanted semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

As an example for how to a aproach a problem that gets to complex to cope with. It is not ment to be an ready to use program to run out of the box.

Its ment to answer the question how to simplify things when "having a lot of trouble getting it to cooperate, and control all the if/else statements." A strategy for such cases if you want.

Also I overdid things a little for demonstration. In practice, you do what seems convenient. Also: I made everything static for simplicity - in a grown application you surely would use instances instead.

**Step 1:** You start with a very simple class frame.  Simplicity is key. Don't put to much in it. Just sketch what you know you want it to do:

```
public class TwentyQuestions{       
   static void mainQuestioning(){
        System.out.println("Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? ");
        String  user = get.nextLine();
        switch(user){
            case "living animal" :
                askLivingAnimalQuestions();
            break;
            case "living plant":
                askLivingPlantQuestions();
            break;
            case "non-living":
                askNoneLivingQuestions();
            break;
            default:
                handleWrongInput();
        }
    }     
 }
```

Sure, that thing above won't compile as the details are not implemented by now(some methods are missing) - But note how the problem has simplified a lot(no nested if's) and most probably you can imidiately see what it is supposed to do. Keeping it simple, straight forward is key.

**Step 2:** Now you can easily create the methods you sketched so far. Lets do that:

```
public class TwentyQuestions{
   static void handleWrongInput(){
      System.err.println("I am no longer playing with you as you don't answer my question properly");
      System.exit(1);
   }
   static void askLivingAnimalQuestions(){
       System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
       switch(user){
          case "feathers":
              askLivinAnimalWithFeathersQuestions();
          break;
          case  "fur":
               askLivinAnimalWithFurQuestions();
          break;
          default:
              handleWrongInput();
       }
   }
   static void askLivingPlantQuestions(){
       System.out.println("is it a tree?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
       if("yes".equals(user)){
           System.out.println("So its a tree!");
           return;
       }
   }
   static void  askNoneLivingQuestions(){
     System.out.println("WhateverNoneLivingQuestion ?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
       switch(user){
         //add possible responses here.
         default:
            handleWrongInput(); 
       }
   }

   static void mainQuestioning(){
        System.out.println("Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? ");
        String  user = get.nextLine();
        switch(user){
            case "living animal" :
                askLivingAnimalQuestions();
            break;
            case "living plant":
                askLivingPlantQuestions();
            break;
            case "non-living":
                askNoneLivingQuestions();
            break;
            default:
                handleWrongInput();
        }
    }     
 }
```

Now I broke the problem down even more. But it still/again won't compile because methods are missing for animals with fur and animals with feathers.

**Step 3:** Implement them as well:

```
public class TwentyQuestions{
   static void handleWrongInput(){
      System.err.println("I am no longer playing with you if you don't answer my question properly");
      System.exit(1);
   }
   static void  askLivinAnimalWithFeathersQuestions(){
      System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?");
      String  user = get.nextLine();
      //don't know how you want to continue;
      //....
   }
   static void askLivinAnimalWithFurQuestions(){
       System.out.println("is it domesticated?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
      //don't know how you want to continue;
      //.... 
   } 
   static void askLivingAnimalQuestions(){
       System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
       switch(user){
          case "feathers":
              askLivinAnimalWithFeathersQuestions();
          break;
          case  "fur":
               askLivinAnimalWithFurQuestions();
          break;
          default:
              handleWrongInput();
       }
   }
   static void askLivingPlantQuestions(){
       System.out.println("is it a tree?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
       if("yes".equals(user)){
           System.out.println("So its a tree!");
           return;
       }
   }
   static void  askNoneLivingQuestions(){
     System.out.println("WhateverNoneLivingQuestion ?");
       String  user = get.nextLine();
       switch(user){
         //add possible responses here.
         default:
            handleWrongInput(); 
       }
   }

   static void mainQuestioning(){
        System.out.println("Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? ");
        String  user = get.nextLine();
        switch(user){
            case "living animal" :
                askLivingAnimalQuestions();
            break;
            case "living plant":
                askLivingPlantQuestions();
            break;
            case "non-living":
                askNoneLivingQuestions();
            break;
            default:
                handleWrongInput();
        }
    }     
 }
```

Note how all your nested if/else that caused you trouble disapeared.

**finish:** Now if you additionally implement the missing questioning and add a Scanner "get" that is initialized in a main(String[] args) you should be there. It should be easy now.

Well..  That probably gives you a lot of methods for 20 nested questions: This is due to the numers of posibilities you have. You have to handle that many cases of questions and answers. No way arround it. 
Better having them cleanly in their own dedicated, place than stray around somewhere(you tidy up and put everything at its place  - the amount of cases/questions you have to handle stays the same).

However in a grown application you may put all your questions and answers in a datastructure like a tree. With that you could avoid the massive amount of methods and have some generalized methods instead that just walk the tree....

*[ Also you can just create interim methods that do nothing ("stubs" ) for things you need but have not implemented yet to make it compile while you still developing.  ]*

Here is the example as a full class, which compiles and does the questioning so far as implemented:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Kai
 */
public class TwentyQuestions {

    static Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

    static void handleWrongInput() {
        System.err.println("I am no longer playing with you if you don't answer my question properly");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    static void askLivinAnimalWithFeathersQuestions() {
        System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?");
        String user = get.nextLine();
        //don't know how you want to continue;
        //....
    }

    static void askLivinAnimalWithFurQuestions() {
        System.out.println("is it domesticated?");
        String user = get.nextLine();
        //don't know how you want to continue;
        //.... 
    }

    static void askLivingAnimalQuestions() {
        System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?");
        String user = get.nextLine();
        switch (user) {
            case "feathers":
                askLivinAnimalWithFeathersQuestions();
                break;
            case "fur":
                askLivinAnimalWithFurQuestions();
                break;
            default:
                handleWrongInput();
        }
    }

    static void askLivingPlantQuestions() {
        System.out.println("is it a tree?");
        String user = get.nextLine();
        if ("yes".equals(user)) {
            System.out.println("So its a tree!");
            return;
        }
    }

    static void askNoneLivingQuestions() {
        System.out.println("WhateverNoneLivingQuestion ?");
        String user = get.nextLine();
        switch (user) {
            //add possible responses here.
            default:
                handleWrongInput();
        }
    }

    static void mainQuestioning() {
        System.out.println("Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? ");
        String user = get.nextLine();
        switch (user) {
            case "living animal":
                askLivingAnimalQuestions();
                break;
            case "living plant":
                askLivingPlantQuestions();
                break;
            case "non-living":
                askNoneLivingQuestions();
                break;
            default:
                handleWrongInput();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainQuestioning();
    }

}
```

**example run:**

```
Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? 
living animal
Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?
fur
is it domesticated?
yes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 30 seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, this way helps a lot more for sure. I tried implementing it, and it seems much easier. But I keep getting a compiling error that is saying the first "static void" is an illegal start of the expression. I implemented a main(string[] args) above and initialized a scanner, but I keep getting this error. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @t.Harlow I copied evering over to my IDE added the Scanner and the main - and it ran. I copied that full file from the IDE and added it to the answer.

Comment: Oh I see where my mistake was! Awesome I am implementing it similar to this, and am adding in all my lines thank you so much for the suggestion, it really helped me out!

Comment: If you want some reading on the topic I found a pdf copy of Wirths(inventor of Pascal among others) writing on it: http://penguin.ewu.edu/%7Etrolfe/Queens/p221-wirth.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You do not have use the if else correctly may be proper indenting and commenting can also help you in this case.

```js
System.out.println("Think of Something");
System.out.println("Is it a living animal, living plant, or non-living thing? ");
String user = get.nextLine();
// start method
if (user.equals("living animal")); { //starts animal tree

  System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?");
  String user2 = get.nextLine();

  if (user2.equals("feathers")); {

    System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?");

  } else if (user2.equals("fur")); {

    System.out.println("is it domesticated?");

  }

} else if (user.equals("living plant")); { //starts plant tree

  System.out.println("is it a tree?");

} // end method
```